# I have an Segment fault( core dumped) in linux VM, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Virtual Machine

Tags: linux

I have an Segment fault( core dumped) error when i execute file after compling.
Being compilation, there are no error or warning.
Can i ask why i got an error below my code?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXBUF 1024
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int server_sockfd, client_sockfd, client_len, n;
char buf[MAXBUF];
struct sockaddr_in clientaddr, serveraddr;
client_len = sizeof(clientaddr);
if ( server_sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP ) ) == -1){perror("socket error : ");
exit(0);
}
memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1])); // input PORT NUMBERSystem call
- network structure
5/39뇌를 자극하는 TCP/IP 소켓 프로그래밍_ 윤상배 _ 윤상배
bind (server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
listen(server_sockfd, 5);
while(1)
{
client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr,
&client_len);
printf("New Client Connect: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr));
memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);
if ((n = read(client_sockfd, buf, MAXBUF) ) <= 0) {
close(client_sockfd);
continue;
}
if (write(client_sockfd, buf, MAXBUF) <=0) {
perror("write error : ");
close(client_sockfd);
}
close(client_sockfd);
}
close(server_sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

solve the error, kind of Segment fault( core dumped)

Comment: Please indent your code. It is unreadable as is.

Comment: @Dang_gu_SU – 
Your program is ill-formed. It has unbalanced parentheses on line 13.